# Существует ли веб интерфейс для SFTP DEBIAN 10?

Tags: docker, sftp

Мне нужно членам команды выдать доступ к sftp серверу, но полный доступ я дать не могу им, я не хочу что бы они файлы удаляли, или скачивали себе.
Существует ли веб интерфейс, что бы например можно было создать подпользователя, и там уже дать ему права только на редактирование и все.
Как это реализвать я хз, друзья говорят что как то с докером связано, хз. Видел такую штуку в панели Pterodactyl, там есть подпользователи, и есть права.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Тогда это будет уже не SFTP

Comment: `на редактирование` — на «редактирование» кого-чего? что вы задумали «редактировать» через «веб-интерфейс»?